# how to correctly store values of selected checkboxes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, checkbox, submit

After searching long time Im unable to find any information on how to best store values of selected checkboxes in rails.

I do something like:

```
  = form_for @profile, :url => request.fullpath, :method => :get,  :html => { :class => 'form-  horizontal' } do |f|
      - @contacts.each do |contact|
        = check_box_tag "contact[#{ contact.slug }]", contact.id, true
        //= label_tag "contact[#{contact.id}]", contact.slug
     = f.submit t('forms.go')
```

On form submit this gives me params:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "contact"=>{"1"=>"bladadie", "2"=>"jolanteds03",
    "3"=>"jannie6674", "4"=>"henriette1305",
    "5"=>"amy6456", "6"=>"jacquelyn9001", "7"=>"florencio4872",
    "8"=>"angel410", "9"=>"rita558", "10"=>"chadd2684", "11"=>"ilene8219",
    "12"=>"sonny664", "13"=>"monique7912", "14"=>"merritt28103744",
    "15"=>"sunny80771258", "16"=>"lavinia31942066", "17"=>"jada29655747",
    "18"=>"johan16227289", "19"=>"cristobal9746087",
    "20"=>"meggie3447530"}, "commit"=>"Go »"}
```

How Would I correctly store the values of those checked, checkboxes?

I'm unable to find any info on this. Hope someone can shed some light!

Comment: I don't understand. What do u mean by store. Do you mean, how you will parse the values ?

Comment: @ManjunathManohar yes saving would be a bette word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your exemple you can iterate through the params:

```
params.each do |key, value|
   contact.create(:id => key, :slug => value
end
```

The create will save them automatically!